# Flash does not reappear after hiding on FB canas app using wmode=direct

Tags: facebook, flash, internet-explorer, visibility, wmode

I'm working on a FB canvas app using Flash with 3D graphics.
I must embed my SWF with param wmode="direct".

On FB, when opening FB UI dialog (such as: purchase credits), FB automatically hides (visibility=hidden) the flash, and after dialog closes, FB returns the old visibility value.

On Chrome and Firefox it works, but on IE, after the dialog closes I checked the flash element style and I saw that visibility=visible, but still the flash is still hidden!

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!
Roei

---

UPDATE: Just for clarify: it works when using wmode is transparent, opaque and window. Just when using "direct" it does not re-appear...